# Gif created with Imagick is not looping (PHP)

Tags: php, animation, gif, imagick

I am using Imagick to create an animated gif from my array of frames. The sample gif I have created animates as expected, but the animation does not loop back to the beginning.

Example variables:

```
$durations = array(100, 100);
$loops = 0; // infinite
```

Main code / create_gif()

```
$gif = new Imagick();
$gif->setFormat('gif');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($frames); $i++) {
    $gif->addImage($frames[$i]);
    $gif->setImageDelay($durations[$i]);
}
$gif->setImageIterations($loops);
$gif = $gif->deconstructImages();
$gif->writeImages('test.gif', true);
```

[Here](http://puu.sh/hc5DT/861f932d56.gif) is my sample gif. As you can see upon loading the page, the man's hair bobs downward (this is just to test, before I spend time on drawing actual frames) and is supposed to loop and bob back up, yet this never happens.

What can I change in order to loop the gif?

---

**EDIT** As requested, here is the (somewhat cut down) code used to build the frames:

```
// Build an array of still frames
$frames = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $frame_num; $i++) {
    // Build an array of image layers
    $layers = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < 11; $j++) {
        $layers[$j] = new Imagick();
        $layers[$j]->readImage('path_to_this_layer.gif');
    }
    // Combine the image layers into a frame
    $frames[$i] = create_frame($layers);
}

// Combine the frames into an animated gif
$gif = create_gif($image_string, $frames, $durations, $loops); 
// create_gif() triggers the code I originally posted
```

create_frame():

```
$frame = new Imagick();
$frame->readImageBlob($layers[0]);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($layers); $i++) {
    if ($layers[$i] != false) {
        $frame->compositeImage($layers[$i], Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
    }
}
$frame->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
return $frame;
```

Comment: How is count of $frames?

Comment: `echo count($frames);` returns `2`

Comment: Can you show code, how you receive $frames?

Comment: @AshotKhanamiryan I have added it to the main post.

Comment: try $gif->setImageIterations(0); instead $loops

Comment: I have, to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Here, all your code is OK. You will search in other place.

Comment: It loops for me on Firefox 37.0.1.  Hair bobs up and down over and over

Comment: It must be something I have not included here, then. I will report back when I ind it! Thanks to both of you for helping me rule out my greatest suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after much fiddling, I found the problem:

`setImageIterations()` must be called **after** `deconstructImages()`

So my working gif_create() function now reads as follows:

```
$gif = new Imagick();
$gif->setFormat('gif');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($frames); $i++) {
    $gif->addImage($frames[$i]);
    $gif->setImageDelay($durations[$i]);
}

// These two were swapped around
$gif = $gif->deconstructImages();
$gif->setImageIterations($loops);

$gif->writeImages('test.gif', true);
```

Hopefully I can save someone else the headache, should they mix these two around also.